# Nodemailer Error: Missing credentials for "PLAIN"

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, nodemailer

Nodemailer was working a few days ago with these exact settings but new im suddenly getting this error. i don't have clientsID, accessToken or anything like that. Im just trying to run this for my school project. Please help.

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer")
const cors = require("cors")({
  origin: true
});

admin.initializeApp();

let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
    user: 'xxxxxxxxxg@gmail.com',
    pass: process.env.GMAIL_PASSWORD,
    port: 587,
    secure: false,
  }
});

exports.emailFirma = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

  cors(req, res, () => {
    const { web, email } = req.body;

    const mailOptions = {
      from: 'noreply@gmail.com',
      to: "xxxxxxxxxxxxg@gmail.com",
      subject: `Mail za potvrdu registracije ${email}`,
      html: `Web adresa firme: ${web}, provjeriti ispravnost e-maila: ${email}`
    };
    return transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (erro) => {
      if (erro) {
        return res.send(erro.toString());
      }
      return res.send('Sent');
    });
  });

});
```

Edit: I enabled "Less secure" apps and Captcha but its still not working..

Answer (score 0):

by console.log(process.env.GMAIL_PASSWORD); before admin initialize code, you may find out that it is undefined. So a quick fix would be putting your password in front of pass in single quotes like this until you find a better way to do it.
pass: 'yourpassword',